# Xcode preview is crashing trying to read a String inside of an entity inside another entity from Core Data

Tags: swift, button, core-data, attributes, entity

firest of all, sorry about my English, it si not my first language. Hope someone can help me.

I am trying to make a button that can edit an entity (jinete, caballo)  inside another entity (collera), but when I try to read an attribute (jinete.nombre, jinete.apellido, caballo.nombre), the preview chars down.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct NuevaColleraView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @State var j1 = Jinete()
    @State var j2 = Jinete()
    @State var c1 = Caballo()
    @State var c2 = Caballo()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    NavigationLink {
                        NuevoJineteView(nuevoJinete: j1)
                    } label: {
                        Text("**\(j1.nombre) \(j1.apellido)**")
                    }
                    NavigationLink {
                        NuevoCaballoView()
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(c1.nombre)")
                    }
                }
                Section {
                    NavigationLink {
                        NuevoJineteView(nuevoJinete: j2)
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(j2.nombre) \(j2.apellido)")
                    }
                    NavigationLink {
                        NuevoCaballoView()
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(c2.nombre)")
                    }
                }
                
                Section {
                    Button("Agregar Collera Nueva") {
                        
                        let nuevaCollera = Collera(context: moc)
                        nuevaCollera.jinete1 = j1
                        nuevaCollera.jinete2 = j2
                        nuevaCollera.caballo1 = c1
                        nuevaCollera.caballo2 = c2
                        
                        try? moc.save()
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Nueva Collera")
        }
    }
}


struct NuevaColleraView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NuevaColleraView()
    }
}
```

Collera is an entity that has Jinete and Caballo as attributes.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension Collera {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Collera> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Collera>(entityName: "Collera")
    }

    @NSManaged public var jinete1: Jinete
    @NSManaged public var jinete2: Jinete
    @NSManaged public var caballo1: Caballo
    @NSManaged public var caballo2: Caballo
    @NSManaged public var criadero: String
    @NSManaged public var puntaje: Int64

}
```

I've been stuck during lots of days on this.

Please help me.

I've tried to add an init to Jinete and Caballo, so they would not be empty objects. but it does not run.

Comment: What is Jinete() and Caballo(), NSManagedObject subclasses (entity) doesn't have such a init by default.

Comment: Jinete() and Caballo() are other entities from core data

Comment: No, what are those init methods? what do they do?

Comment: `Jinete()` is short for `Jinete.init()`, and you can't initialize like that `NSManagedObject`, it needs at least a context.